# Reloaded page after setAttribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, dom

I create an simply function to switch from light to dark mode of my page with using VueJS, but my problem is not because of him, here is code:

```
    <a @click="toggleTheme"  class="switch-mode" href>
      <div class="switch-mode-btn">

      </div>
    </a>

toggleTheme() {
    let currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    currentTheme == 'darkMode' ? currentTheme = '' : currentTheme = 'darkMode';

    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', currentTheme);
}
mounted() {
    let localTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', localTheme);
},
```

css

```
:root {

    /* LIGHT MODE */
    --background-color: #fcfcfc;
    --text-color: rgba(17, 24, 39);
    /* END LIGHT MODE */
}

[data-theme="darkMode"] {
    /* DARK MODE */
    --background-color: rgba(17, 24, 39);
    --text-color: #fcfcfc;
    /* END DARK MODE */
}
```

why, when i launch my `toogleTheme` function, my page is reloaded? I want to do this dynamically but without refreshing my page :(

thanks for any help

Comment: how you call `toggleTheme` method? and you are using vue cli or cdn?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudi I add code at the top of post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `href` from the `a` tag. The empty `href` is causing the reload.

Answer (score 3):

### `Solution 1 :`

use `.prevent` modifier when you call your method

```
<a @click.prevent="toggleTheme"  class="switch-mode" href>
   <div class="switch-mode-btn">

   </div>
</a>
```

you can read more about modifiers in the docs : [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

### `Solution 2 :`

just remove the `href` attribute from your `<a>` tag